# How to change email for 2 step verfifation?

Tags: authentication, account

I don't have access to my email to log in anymore, it was disabled by Google. How can I pass the 2-step verification without the email?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add some more context for someone to be able to answer this question. What are you trying to log into? How do you expect to skip 2-step verification on this site? Why can't you use a different email address? And so on.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. I was referring to Mailgun, sorry for the confusion...Any insights?

Comment: I don't know anything about mailgun, sorry. You should edit the question, its title, and its tags to get people who know about mailgun to look at it. Otherwise no one will both trying to answer it.